# Writing pyspark dataframe to s3 location using partition

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, data-partitioning

I have a dataframe of size 3.7 million relatively small with a date column(01-01-2018 to till date) and a partner column along with other unique ids.I want to write the data frame to s3 location by partitioning it by date first and then partner(5 partners for instance P1,P2,P3,P4 and P5). Below is my schema and code

```
df schema is 
id1: long
id2: long
id3: long
partner: string
dt: date
```

```
df = df1.select('dt','partner').distinct().groupBy('partner').agg(F.collect_set('dt').alias('dt'))
dummy_list = []
for i in df.collect():
  dummy_list.append(i.partner)
  for src in dummy_list:
    for dt1 in i.dt:
      df.filter(F.col('dt') == dt1).filter(F.col('partner') == src).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://test/parquet/dt={}/partner={}".format(datetime.strftime(dt1,'%Y-%m-%d'),src))
```

the above code runs successfully but it is taking more than 4-5 hours(i cancelled it midway) to write the dataframe in the s3 location. Any ways I can reduce the time significantly? Can anyone help me validate the code or correct the code if necessary in order to achieve this faster. I am new to this, appreciate any help.

Sample Data

```
id1|id2|id3|partner|dt
100|200|300|p1     |01-01-2018
101|200|30 |p2     |01-01-2020
102|202|311|p3     |01-01-2019
103|201|320|p4     |01-02-2019
104|210|305|p5     |01-03-2018 
.
.
.
```

Comment: you need to use partitionBy clause, the method you are using is wrong.

Comment: the problem with that is I am using data bricks notebook and it doesnt support hive meta store yet. I need to stage this in presto which uses hive meta store. So there is no way to connect both if i use the partitionBy clause. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: `Every Databricks deployment has a central Hive metastore accessible by all clusters to persist table metadata. Instead of using the Databricks Hive metastore, you have the option to use an existing external Hive metastore instance or the AWS Glue Catalog.`

Comment: So i just created using the partition by clause and wrote it in S3 parquet path. Created an external table using HQL from pycharm and also gave the partition by clause. But when i query for the data in Presto. It returns zero rows. What could be the problem?